# Difference between dependencies(basic and enhanced) from Stanford CoreNLP?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, chatbot

Difference between basic-dependencies,collapsed-dependencies and collapsed-ccprocessed-dependencies in Stanford CoreNLP and how to use them to understand query?

Answer (score 4):

A good way to see the difference by example is with the online demo ([corenlp.run](http://corenlp.run)). basic, collapsed, and cc-processed are roughly the old ("Stanford Dependencies") equivalents to basic, enhanced, and enhanced++ in the newer ("[Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/introduction.html)") representation.

At a high level, the basic dependencies are meant to be easier to parse -- e.g., they're always a tree, the label set is small, etc. The enhanced[++] dependencies (like their predecessors, "collapsed" and "cc-processed") are deterministic transformations on the basic dependencies that are intended to make them a bit easier to work with, and a bit more semantic. For example, by labelling a preposition on the arc (`prep:of` in Stanford Dependencies; `nmod:of` in Universal Dependencies).

The full documentation of the differences (for Universal Dependencies) can be found in: [Schuster and Manning (2016). *"Enhanced English Universal Dependencies: An Improved Representation for Natural Language Understanding Tasks"*](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/schuster2016enhanced.pdf). The original Stanford Dependencies are perhaps best documented in the [Stanford Dependencies Manual](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Gabor...How to use these dependencies to understand intent (subject/object etc.)of queries?

Comment: There is often an edge type corresponding to the relationship you want. For example, nsubj for subject, and dobj for object. You may also be interested in OpenIE (either Stanford's, or there's Ollie, OpenIE4, etc.), which uses dependencies to extract subject/relation/object triples.

Comment: TL;DR regarding enhanced++: "there exist several phenomena for which both the _basic_ UD representation and the _enhanced_ UD representation provide suboptimal analyses. For this reason, we argue for another representation which allows for the deletion of relations from the basic UD tree, as this gives us more flexibility in analyzing several constructions in English [...]. We therefore introduce _enhanced++_ UD graphs and propose different analyses for the following common phenomena in English."